# how to comment for both answers and question in Question/Answer module?

Tags: comments

I am using the [Question / Answer](https://www.drupal.org/project/question_answer) module.

However, it can not be attached to Answer it is possible to attach the comment only Question.

I think Answer also I want to put a comment.

How would it?

Comment: Which type of issue you are facing